# AZURE: Change the PRIORITY Rule configuration in a network security group via PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I cannot make  it work,  please  review below code

```
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name MYNSG001 -ResourceGroupName MYRG

$nsg | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name MYRULE

Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name MYRULE -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -Priority 110
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points that you missed:

1. You need to use `Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` at last.
2. You need to provide all required security rule parameters, not only `Priority`, it is not allowed when using `Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup`.

You could try my sample command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "NSG name" -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"
$nsg | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "Port_8080" 
$config = Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "Port_8080" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg -Priority 110 -Protocol "*" -Access "Allow" -Direction "Inbound" -SourceAddressPrefix "Internet" -SourcePortRange "*" -DestinationAddressPrefix "*" -DestinationPortRange "8080"
$config | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

[image]

For more details about the parameters, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azurermps-6.11.0).

Comment: Works  like  Magic,  I have tried  it and it works  perfectly fine... Thank you

Comment: what if i wanted to only change the Priority value and let other parameters stay on their current settings...?

Comment: @KeithlynnR You may not do that, if you do not specific other settings, it will give an error.